# python:mysql_config not found when connecting to Mysql DB

Tags: python, mysql

Im trying to connect mysql through python and have the following packages installed.

> apt-get install python-pip
>
> pip install flask
>
> apt-get install python-mysqldb
>
> pip install flask-restful

After searching few of the posts, tried installing the below too: (which doesnt seem to work or is not installing)

> apt install libmysqlclient-devel
>
> easy_install mysql-python
>
> pip install MySQL-python

**My python version :**  Python 2.7.12

In my script im using:

```
import MySQLdb
```

And in my command if i try:

> python nameserver.py

I get the error as:

```
import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Comment: try with `apt-get purge python-mysqldb` then `pip install MySQL-python
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve to use this:

first, install `build-essential` with this:

`apt install build-essential`

and then, install `libmysqlclient-dev` with this:

`apt install libmysqlclient-dev`

then try install `mysqlclient` with pip like this:

`pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: in Centos, you can install it "yum install mysql-dev"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use PyMysql . I found it quite easy to use .

Here is an example :

```
    import pymysql

    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='<username>', passwd='<password>', db='mysql')

    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT <Column> FROM <Table>")
```

Here you can find out more about pyMysql : 
https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

Comment: After changing the new code and commenting the old one, if i run filename.py in cmd, why does it still consider the old code and through the same error, is there any restart mechanism in python..